# decayed learning rate in CNN

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to implement a CNN with a callback for learning rate decay (using keras/tensorflow), with Adam optimizer:

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_decayed_lr = self.model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32).numpy()
        print("current decayed lr: {:0.7f}".format(current_decayed_lr))
```

But I get the following error message:

```
current_decayed_lr = self.model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32).numpy()

AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute '_decayed_lr'
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the revisied version of keras optimizer API, `decay` is deprecated. But the previous optimizer is placed under legacy namespace. You can try from that, but note, it would be good to adopt the new API for future case.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam

inp = keras.Input((2,))
out = layers.Dense(2)(inp)
model = keras.Model(inp, out)
model.compile(Adam(0.01, decay=0.001), loss='mse')

class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_decayed_lr = self.model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32).numpy()
        print("current decayed lr: {:0.7f}".format(current_decayed_lr))

x = y = np.random.randn(32, 2) 
model.fit(x, y, callbacks=[CustomCallback()], epochs=10)
```

```
current decayed lr: 0.0100000
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 661ms/step - loss: 2.6350
current decayed lr: 0.0099900
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.5868
current decayed lr: 0.0099800
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 2.5394
current decayed lr: 0.0099701
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 2.4927
current decayed lr: 0.0099602
```

Comment: Executing your example script gives:

RandomKernelLaunch, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), key, counter, gen, data, size, dist) status: INTERNAL: Cuda call failed with 98 srun: error: nid007852: task 0: Aborted (core dumped)

A CUDA error is very strange, because i'm on AMD GPUs and installed tensorflow-rocm in my environment.

Comment: You can run the above code in colab, it will work without any error. I'm using TF 2.12.

Comment: Yes true, in colab it works without any problem. The only difference is that I am using AMD GPUs and tensorflow-rocm (also 2.12). I've no idea why it gives a CUDA related error message.

Comment: Without the callback, can you run the code?

Comment: No it already fails in line "out = layers.Dense(2)(inp)"